# List Item iOS highlight style in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-widget

Is it possible to add a iOS style list item highlighting like the one for the material design (`InkWell`) in Flutter? If you know iOS, there's a default `UITableView` highlighting when holding/tapping a list item.

Here's an example of what I mean.

[image: image description]